# How to get the user ID token after sign-in on the web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase-admin for node.js and firebase for react.
I want to get access token to send it to my server in header for defend my data.
I use this code on react app

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(form.elements.email.value, form.elements.password.value)
                .then((result) => {
                        console.log(result)
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                });
```

but I dont know how to get token from result.
Or i have some ways to work with API on my server?
It should work like this: 
if user want to get to admin panel, he should sign in. Client get token, set in cookie ans use with any request?

Comment: so ... what **is** result?

Comment: `signInWithEmailAndPassword` doesn't give you an access token..

Comment: @PeterHaddad , `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(form.elements.email.value, form.elements.password.value)
                .then((result) => {
                        console.log(result)
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
                        .then((q) => console.log(q))
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                }); ` 
it work slow((

Comment: getIdToken gives you the token, what is the problem there?

Comment: Why use `getIdToken(true)`? This will unnecessarily force a new IdToken after you just created one by logging in. Use `getIdToken()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The ID token is not available in the data returned from `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.  What you can do instead is follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and use [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#get-idtoken) to get the token after sign-in finishes.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

The linked documentation goes on to explain how to validate the token on the backend using the Firebase Admin SDK.